# AngularJS and Thymeleaf

Tags: angularjs, select, thymeleaf

I too am wondering if Thymeleaf and AngularJS can be used together.

Which one would be rendered 1st?

If you have a Thymeleaf select...  and want to let AngularJS feed a  commandsBySection data list as below...

```
 <select id="tl1_com_sel" th:field="*{command}" ng-model="tl1Data.command" >
      <option selected="selected" value="">  select an option  </option>
      <option th:each="command: ${<b>commandsBySection}"
              th:value="${command}"
              th:text="${command}">COMMAND</option>
 </select>
```

you would end up with ${{{commandsBySection}}} ...

I'm new to these technologies.... are there examples of AngularJS rendered select in a Thymeleaf page?

Answer (score 2):

They could be used together, the key point to remember is that the output of Thymeleaf is generated server-side before the resulting page is transferred to the client browser. Once rendered on the browser AngularJS comes in to play client-side.

I've never done this and I would imagine it would be a headache to develop all your AngularJS pages using Thymeleaf because:

1. Thymeleaf will assume it's being used to generate HTML and will need to be written in valid XHTML so the schema checking in Thymeleaf will need to know about AngularJS's attributes and any custom elements.
2. None of the AngularJS development/IDE tools will understand the Thymeleaf templates in your browser so you'll have to keep a server running to serving page in order to see what you're doing.
3. The comprehensive AngularJS support for test won't work because the files will be Thymeleaf files, not AngularJS HTML files.

However, if you just use Thymeleaf to render HTML snippets on the server and have your AngularJS app dynamically display these it could work nicely.

So, to answer your question, the Thymeleaf template is rendered first, on the server, then the AngularJS page is rendered by the browser on the client. To use them together to make Thymeleaf generate an AngularJS page is probably not a good idea but using them in a project together would be fine.